# Floated div has a margin that is breaking the flow

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have two divs: floated left and floated right. The margin on the right div is breaking the left div, making it appear lower on the page than it should be. **I want both divs to touching the top**.

HTML:

```
 <div class="right_div">
            This div is in the right place.
        </div>

    <div class="clear"> </div>

    <div class="left_div">

This div should be at the top</div>
```

CSS:

```
.right_div {

    float: right;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color:blue;
}

 .left_div{

    margin-left: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: tomato;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 10em;

 }

.clear {

    clear:both;
}
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/eLSc8/

Answer (score 4):

remove

```
<div class="clear"> </div>
```

try this

```
<div class="right_div">
            This div is in the right place.
        </div>

    <div class="left_div">
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have articulated better. I'm trying to get both divs to the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

remove the

```
<div class="clear"> </div>
```

and the red element will stay on top.
As a sidenote, empty markup placed for styling purpose only should be avoided. If you need to apply a float clearing somewhere you should use non-structural approach like *easyclearing* and modern variants (e.g. see the `.clearfix` class of [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/))

Comment: Sorry, I should have articulated better. I'm trying to get both divs to the top of the page.

Comment: If you remove that div that is the resulting effect. the div `right` has just a margin-top applied (remove it).

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/eLSc8/1/

please remove this clearboth

```
<div class="clear"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is saying; you can lose the clearing div. 
Then simply add a float left to your other div to align it.
Depending on your structure and how you want it positioned, you might need to contain them or add margin. check jsfiddle.net/RSy6F/2/

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/eLSc8/4/ ?

HTML:

```
<div class="left_div">This div should be at the top</div>
<div class="right_div">This div is in the right place.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.right_div {
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color:blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    height: 2.2em;
}
.left_div {
    position:absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background-color: tomato;
    height: 2.2em;
}
```